# How can i fetch the average number of email sent this month in the database by sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i fetch the average number of email sent this month in the database by sql query

Details: **Database- MYSQL**

colums: `ID, email,date, url,keywords,etc......`
I am unable to calculate the **daily average** number of email sent in last 3 months, Please help me with the query

[I have added the stats in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyH6D.png) 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question and post what you have tried so far and what is not working.

Comment: daily average, monthly average? Please post sample data and expected results to help us answer your question.

Comment: Hello @NevilleKuyt I have updated the image of the colums in the above question? Let me know please if it works

Comment: The image doesn't match the columns in your question - is there one row in the database for each email you've sent?

Comment: Yes On the basis if the ID there is a column which show the number of emails sent by that id and the date on which it is sent. Like    On date 1 this ID has sent 4 emails. For next day counr NEW id was generated for the count

Comment: How can I found daily average daily average, I have written the query select Avg(mail_sent) from Table 1 where date >= '2018-03-01' ;          ................Please confirm the average i got is daily average?

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(mail_sent)/ DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL  -3 MONTH))
from table
where date>DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL  -3 MONTH)
```

Hope It helps

Comment: You need to be clear exactly what each column represents and the desired output based on the data provided.  For instance I can only guess that the total emails sent in your example is 6038.  But there is no way to display a daily average over 3 months based on data that only represents part of 1 day.  Perhaps if you could attach a table with more data (clearly explained) someone can give an example without having to enter the data for you as well - just trying to help you get an answer!

Comment: One can only provide sample data. You will have to assume that the table will have records for more than a day.

Comment: As I said - helping you with code is one thing, creating a database and table and fields and populating them with test data is another.  Unless you can actually provide enough test data as sql so people can test solutions I do not think you will get much assistance